# Question about graph minors and average degree

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minors

Let's define the following two properties first. A graph $G$ is called dense if it has no minors that have a higher average degree.
A $k$-chromatic graph $G$ is called saturated if every minor of $G$ is $k$-colorable, (or not having $K_{k+1}$ as minor if we assume Hadwiger conjecture).

I was trying to came up with properties and examples of dense graphs, and had the conjecture that all dense graphs are also saturated. If someone could come up with a counter example or a proof, or any other interesting property of dense graphs, that would be great.

Comment: To be honest, my first reaction here is "you can't call that 'dense', the word is already taken".

Comment: The square pyramid graph is a counter example. It 3-chromatic, but has $K_4$ as a minor (so not 3-colorable), and it is dense.